# replace variable with in the given string with json object

Tags: javascript

I am having sample template like below i want to replace baby.name with json object values how to do this please help me to solve this.

```
var Template = 'Welcome to the world baby {{baby.name}}'

const namelist= [{school:"hakvoz",baby: { name: 'shanker' }}];
```

with help of string replace need to achieve this.
Output want like this "Welcome to the world baby shanker"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` `/\{{2}(.+)\}{2}/` to match `"{{"` capture one or more characters, e.g., `"baby.name"` and `"}}"`, `.split()` with `"."` as parameter to get `"baby"`, `"name"`, utilize  bracket notation or destructuring assignment to get properties at object within `namelist` array

```js
var Template = 'Welcome to the world baby {{baby.name}}';

const namelist= [{school:"hakvoz",baby: { name: 'shanker' }}];

let template = Template.replace(/\{{2}(.+)\}{2}/, function(match, p1) {
  let [prop, key] = p1.split(".");
  return namelist[0][prop][key];
});

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = template;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'baby' of undefined   in this line return namelist[0][prop][key];

Answer (score 0):

You might have to look at [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

`string text ${expression} string text`

So your case becomes

```
var Template = 'Welcome to the world baby ${namelist[0].baby.name}'
```